# How would you translate: Be sure to bring enough water

Tags: translation, grammar, adjectives

够，enough, is a kind of adjective that can only be used as a predicate, not as a modifier.
水够了 is "The water is enough" -- here it is used as a predicate.
We cannot say, however: 够水， using 够 as a modifier, like we would with another adjective: 热水
So in an English sentence that uses "enough" as a modifier, like "Be sure to bring enough water", how would you translate it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use 足够, for example, 足够的水. It can be used both predicatively and attributively.

The sentence could be translated to 一定要带足够的水。Or more naturally 记得要带足够的水. In this case, 多 can also be added, so it becomes 足够多的水; 足够 is used adverbially.

Comment: In your examples it seems that 足够 is being used adjectivally rather than adverbially...Am I confused?

Comment: @Buddy L In 足够的水, it’s used adjectivally, while in 足够多的水, advervially, modifying the adjective 多

Comment: Of course! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It's a hot summer day, you are going for a long walk over sparsely wooded tinder-dry mountain, somewhere in Spain.

Be sure to bring enough water!
确保带够水！

Comment: Interesting....would 够 be considered a resultative of 带 here rather than a modifier of 水？

Comment: Not too familiar with Linguistese. What I can say is, 够, here representing 'enough', is a quantity or amount, presumably, but not necessarily, greater than none.

Comment: It's actually an interesting distinction. If it's a rusultative of 带, then it is specifying the extent to which the water was brought. If it's a modifier of  水, then it would be describing the amount of water that was brought. I think in this case it is a resultative of 带, because if you rearranged the sentence it is much more likely that 够 will stay to the right of 带, rather than to the left of 水：水都带够了, but you would never say *够水都带了

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand what you mean by "a resultative" Do you have a definition of that? A link maybe?? Do you mean somehow the result of bringing something? In this case, the result of bringing is "have enough water" Or you mean 够 is something like "enoughly"??

Comment: Resultat complements, or some people call them resultative verbs, are like complementary verbs/adjectives that goes after a main verb. In 看完书, 完 is the result. In 我吃饱了， 饱 is the result complement. A great (and concise) article: http://www.ctcfl.ox.ac.uk/Grammar%20exercises/RVC.htm

Comment: Interesting link, thanks. My understanding (I may be wrong) is, a complement is something which is not necessary in a sentence. It supplies additional information which is good but not absolutely necessary in the sentence. If I remove 够 from 水都带够了。the meaning is completely changed. Thus 够 cannot be a complement.

Comment: You are correct that a complement is not necessary in a sentence, but that doesn't mean that once it is included it doesn't have a fundamental impact on the meaning. 我吃饱了，我看完了, 饱 and 完 are classic examples of result complements. If you took them out of their respective sentences, the sentence would make sense but mean something completely different: 我吃了，我看了. Likewise, you could say “水都带了”, and it would mean something different. I am inclined to think that in the sentence we are playing with here, 够 is in fact a result complement （for 带），not a describer （of 水）because you would never say *够水带了